# Erro no querry builder do codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

Estou com um problema no SQL da minha query, segue:

```
$sql = "SELECT
                cl.codigo,
                pa.codigo AS codigo_participante,
                pa.nome AS nome_participante,
                cl.usuario,
                cr.data AS data_geracao,
                cl.validade,
                cl.chave
            FROM
                participante pa,
                conta_receber cr,
                parcela_conta_receber pcr,
                chave_liberacao cl
            WHERE
                pa.codigo = cr.codigo_participante
                AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM cl.validade) = '2017'
                AND cr.numero = pcr.numero_conta_receber
                --AND pcr.codigo_chave_liberacao = cl.codigo
                --AND pa.codigo = 23
            GROUP BY
                cl.codigo,
                pa.codigo,
                pa.nome,
                cl.usuario,
                cr.data,
                cl.validade,
                cl.chave";

    $resultado = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Quando eu rodo essa mesma query no banco, ele me retorna, mas quado é no codigo é 0 o resultado, existe algum problema nessa query?

Explicar melhor, esse sql ai em cima eu carrego no model para preencher uma lista na view. Como a querry é muito complexa, eu não estou usando o querry builder no **codeigniter**, sinceramente, eu nem saberia como usa-lo nessa querry. Enfim, quando eu uso o método `$this->db->query($sql)`, ele me retorna um array vazio, só que, esse mesmo sql, colocado no meu SGBD retorna várias tuplas. Eu cheguei a ver que existem outras pessoas com erros similares, quando a querry é muito complexa, o **codeigniter** não consegue executa-la corretamente, retornando um array vazio. Só que, ai vem o pulo do gato, quando eu retiro duas condições do `WHERE`, o `$this->db->query($sql)` me retorna vários valores, as duas linhas estão indicadas como comentários no código acima.

Comment: Não dá erro nenhum na sua query?
Os erros estão habilitados no CI? Já tentou trocar o EXTRACT () por YEAR(cl.validade) = '2017'?

Comment: Cara, o pior que não dá erro, isso é que mais me encabula. Sim, os erros estão habilitados. Vou testar essa querry que você informou.

Comment: Guilherme, eu creio que esse YEAR é do mysql, e esse banco é postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro, foi bem besta, o problema estava no nome do banco que tinha um espaço em branco, como o banco não conectava ele não retornava nada.

Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, desculpe pelo erro tão besta.
:(

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual o banco ou IDE que você está rodando essa Query, mas achei estranho os comentários "--" no meio dela. Não sei se a função de QUERY do CodeIgniter vai reconhecer isso e interpretar do jeito certo. Sugiro que retire esse trecho e rode novamente.

> --AND pcr.codigo_chave_liberacao = cl.codigo
>
> --AND pa.codigo = 23

Comment: Amilton, essas linhas comentadas era so para destacar que são elas que causam o erro. Mas eu fiz um teste, o querry builder entende as linhas comentadas. Mas eu ja descobri qual é o erro. O problema era um espaço no nome do banco, ele não conseguia conectar no banco por que tinha um espaço em branco, tipo: bd_name=> 'nomedobanco '.